# Using kubectl.exe within Docker and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to run my [kubectl.exe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-windows/) file within Docker.

kubectl version is 1.26.2 and the Kustomize version is v4.5.7.

I'm able to run everything successfully locally with a npm start. But if I instead try to run it in a docker container, I get error:
Command failed: /app/src/core/Kubernetes/kubectl.exe config set-cluster abc-def-dev-wu2 --server=https://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx --insecure-skip-tls-verify

Here is my js file:

```
    import { execSync } from 'child_process'
    import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
    import path from 'path';
    
    export const loginKubernetes = ({ kubernetesNamespace }) =>{
       
        try{
      
            const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)); // finds file directory location. 
            
            const username = process.env.KUBERNETES_USER
            const password = process.env.KUBERNETES_PASS
    
            // Loggin to Kubernetes         
            const kubectl = path.join(__dirname, './kubectl.exe');; // not installed local, so have to reference file.
    
            const server = 'https://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx';
            const cluster = 'abc-def-dev-wu2';
            const namespace = kubernetesNamespace;
            
            execSync(`${kubectl} config set-cluster ${cluster} --server=${server} --insecure-skip-tls-verify`);
......
```

And my Docker file:

```
# Base Img
FROM node:19-alpine3.16

# Create working directory 
WORKDIR /app

# Install application dependencies
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

# Copy scripts to the folder
COPY . /app

# Needs to be the same as host we are using for node specified in the index.
EXPOSE 8080

# Start application
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Things that I can confirm:

1. It works when I run it locally with npm start.
2. console.log(kubectl) the route is correctly pointing to the kubectl.exe file within Docker.
3. I can ping https://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx from within Docker successfully
4. All .env variables are set up properly. Docker exec -it  env

Any suggestions on what else could be the cause are appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: That Dockerfile looks like it's an ordinary Linux image; are you trying to run a Windows `*.exe` program in it?  Can you use a [Kubernetes client library](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) rather than trying to run `kubectl` as a subprocess?

Comment: I'll take a look at doing that instead today. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David Maze stated, the biggest issue here is I'm trying to run a .exe in a Linux environment. As he states, I can bypass this issue entirely by downloading client to my node.js package. This resolved my issue.